# Symbol or abbreviation for a particle?

Tags: interlinear-gloss, particles

Not sure if this is a silly question, but: is there a standardised symbol or abbreviation that can be used in formal definitions to refer to particles?

Writing "PARTICLE" or "PART" sounds...silly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In interlinear glosses, I think `PTC` or `PTCL` are most commonly used to abbreviate "particle".
`PRT` or `PART` are sometimes used too, but should rather be avoided due to confusion with "preterite" and "participle", respectively.
But the name actually doesn't matter that much given that you provide a list of the abbreviations that you used with their intended meaning (which is always good practice to do because of the lack of a definite universal standardisation).

In formal definitions, I generally wouldn't use abbreviations but always terminology as precise as possible.

For further reference:

- [Leipzig Glossing Rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/pdf/Glossing-Rules.pdf) – probably the most standard-like
- [Extension of the Leipzig Glossing rules](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/books/9783110311358/9783110311358.xxv/9783110311358.xxv.xml) (I didn't compare it in much detail, but the original Leipzig rules don't include an abbreviation for "particle")
- [List of glossing abbreviations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations)